# Is there a tool which lists exported methods from a DLL?

Tags: com, dll

As the question states - is there a good tool out there which lists methods an unmanaged DLL exports? I would like it to list COM methods and interfaces too.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

For DLLs, use the Dependency Viewer ([depends.exe](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc738370.aspx)).

For COM objects, use [oleview.exe](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?familyid=5233b70d-d9b2-4cb5-aeb6-45664be858b6&displaylang=en)

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [Dependency Walker](http://www.dependencywalker.com/) to get a list of unmanaged functions exported from a DLL.

You can't easily get a l list of COM classes exported from a DLL. What you'd have to do is something like to through the registry and find all objects that reference the DLL in question. DLLs advertise their classes via registration in the registry...

Answer (score 0):

As an application packager we use a utility that monitors (or dumps) the registration information - WiseComCapture.exe - this is part of Wise Package Studio however which isn't free.
It spits out a .reg file of all it's registration information.

A bit of noodling around with google may 'expose' it