# any tool which can list methods out from the dlls?

Tags: winapi, visual-c++, dll, com

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is there a tool which lists exported methods from a DLL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/195571/is-there-a-tool-which-lists-exported-methods-from-a-dll)

I am wondering whether there are tools/API which can list method from native dll/com dll?
Preferably using code.

Comment: edit question, basically I prefer to list methods using code.

Comment: Also command line tools is prefered over GUI tool

Comment: Note that all you get are the function names. You don't get the parameters or any documentation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this: 
http://dependencywalker.com/